# Positive translation for "self-fulfilling prophecy"

Tags: перевод

I know the word накликать, which has for me a meaning like "tempting fate" (pulling in bad luck), but is there a word in Russian which gives "self-fulfilling prophecy" a positive meaning? Something that has the sense: "believe and it will happen"?

Comment: There's a Russian proverb, "Дурни думками богатеют" (Fools get rich with their thoughts), that is, 'only fools want to get rich by mere thinking of it and not doing anything to accomplish it' is it what you're looking for? ))

Comment: Well, there's the calque, `самосбывающееся пророчество`.

Comment: Funny thing, there are common words for pulling bad luck by bad predictions (накаркать, накликать), pulling bad luck by good predictions (сглазить), and a tradition of wishing good luck by bad prediction ("ни пуха, ни пера"). But the connection between good prediction and good luck seem to be uncommon.

Comment: I think, that if one says something good will happen and it happens, we do not call it any kind of "prophecy". One of the reasons might be that if everything went well, there is no reason to blame any supernatural forces (накликать is initially derived from кликать which is more or less synonym to звать).

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy, на мой взгляд, более правильно "самоисполняющееся". В поисковиках "самосбывающееся" тоже популярно, но это звучит как-то странно, не по-русски. Или мне кажется?

Comment: There is a saying *Мечтать не вредно.* which may seem positive but is often used negatively.

Answer (score 2):

You can say "предсказать". It is not positive, but neutral word.
Usually it used about prophets. For example:

> Кассандра предсказала падение Трои. / Cassandra predicted the fall of
>   Troy.

Comment: "Предсказать" doesn't involve any attraction of either good or bad luck. It means just "to predict", i.e. to provide some information about the future, but not to influence it.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it souds like: если сильно захотеть - обязательно сбудется.

Comment: Если сильно захотеть - можно в космос полететь.

Comment: На эту же тему: если долго мучиться, что‐нибудь получится.

Comment: V.V. если про "космос" еще можно согласиться, то "долго мучится и что-нибудь получится" - это СОВСЕМ не то, что интересовало автора.

Comment: Полагаю, это юмор, а не буквальное восприятие.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it's useful,but there's an expression *привлечь удачу*(to attract luck),though you can hear *поймать удачу(за хвост)*,*ловить миг удачи* (catching luck,or a lucky moment ) more often in Russian. And when a person visits a fortune teller there's *приворот на счастье*(some magic to bring luck).

Answer (score 2):

Антоним к `накликать беду` - `приманить/привлечь удачу`.

Answer (score 2):

Приняли волю пророка.

Они смирились с нарисованной картиной будущего, и стали действовать согласно ролям, предписываемой им, этой картиной.

Действовали грезя о будущем, приближая неизбежность свершившегося/будущего.

---

**EDIT**

Но все ествественно гораздо проще, мы смотрим в гугл и обнаруживаем что вики знает:

[Self-fulfilling prophecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-fulfilling_prophecy) для не носителей и для носителей [Самоисполняющееся пророчество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)

> A self-fulfilling prophecy is a prediction that directly or indirectly causes itself to become true, by the very terms of the prophecy itself, **due to positive feedback between belief and behavior**. Although examples of such prophecies can be found in literature as far back as ancient Greece and ancient India, it is 20th-century sociologist Robert K. Merton who is credited with coining the expression "self-fulfilling prophecy" and formalizing its structure and consequences. In his 1948 article Self-Fulfilling Prophecy, Merton defines it in the following terms:

- The self-fulfilling prophecy is, in the beginning, a false definition of the situation evoking a new behavior which makes the original false conception come true. This specious validity of the self-fulfilling prophecy perpetuates a reign of error. For the prophet will cite the actual course of events as proof that he was right from the very beginning.

Речь идет **не** об удаче или не удаче, а о некотором варианте самообмана, акте веры, *который* приводит к последствиям согласно этой вере, но в тоже время эти последствия могли бы и не случиться, если бы эта вера принята не была. Те следствия, являются прямыми последствиями некоторого самообмана.

Простейший пример, действия в критической ситуации, действия в ситуации связанной с выживанием. Басня о лягушках и кувшине с молоком, как раз из этой оперы.

Те в исходном варианте, речь о вере и убежденности в некоторое вероятное будущее, в возможные события этого будущего, которые меняют способы действия самого человека(носителя этих убеждений) и тем самым меняет вероятный исход для этого человека в будущем, на тот который соответствует этим убеждениям.

В таком ключе можно предполагать или вообразить себе, как положительный смысл так и отрицательный. Однако в положительных вариантах, это результаты целеустремленности и полного использование своих возможностей, для которого(использования) следует знать эти возможности. Те это результат не самообмана, а объективной оценки имеющихся возможностей. Да, при этом действиям может сопутствовать удача, или можно положиться на удачу - но в любом случае это максимальное использование имеющихся возможностей с объективной(те соответствующей реальности) оценкой, и не важно сопутствовало этому удача или нет.

Можно обманываться относительно возможностей, в сторону завышения, но это либо ничего не изменит или (и с большей вероятностью) приведет к неудаче.

Недооценка собственных возможностей, те самообман, в сторону их занижения, гарантированно приведет к отсутствию действий по реализации этих возможностей, и гарантированно отрицательным последствиям в ситуациях в которых это вообще имеет смысл обсуждать, в критических или могущих стать таковыми ситуациях, как минимум.

К сожалению ОП не привел вариантов положительного использования этого термина в английском языке. Также я не исключаю что возможно для носителей языка термин имеет нейтральную окраску, и приобретает соответствующую в зависимости от контекста где он использован.

Варианты использования которые довелось слышать мне, имеют явно негативную окраску, в духе: гуси уже во всю гогочут, а вы все спите.

Более чем уверен, что классики отечественной литературы в результате работы над смыслами, имеют образцы и такого смысла, и мне кажется что этому вопросу требуется человек с литературным образованием, который мог бы привести варианты использования этого смысла примерами из золотого и серебряного века.

Есть также другие определения этого термина: самореализующееся пророчество, эффект Розенталя, эффект Пигмалиона.

Comment: This answer looks off-topic and doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Lara Вы можете рассматривать это, как попытку литературного, художественного, поэтического переревода, перевод на эзопов язык. Я совсем не поэт, но не смотря на то, что  в результате мозгового шторма я всетаки не смог до конца поймать и выразить ту мысль которая, как мне показалась, была у меня на тот момент, тем не менее, я в какой то степени доволен получившимся результатом. Ни один из ответов, на данный момент, не отражает и не передает смысл, того контекста в котором я слышал употребление “self-fulfilling prophecy” в английском языке.

Comment: Я сам, хотел бы увидеть качественный перевод этого словсочетания, это очень интересная и важная для понимания, смысловая единица. Тут бы нам для этого ответа профессионального лингвиста и литератора надо бы.

Comment: Спасибо за старание и желание ответить на действительно непростой вопрос! Вполне возможно, что если это довести до ума, то получится хороший ответ. Прежде всего, можете перевести Ваш текст (или это отдельные предложения?) на английский, чтобы было понятно, как соотнести Ваш ответ с вопросом, и где там укакзанные в вопросе выражения? Также было бы неплохо написать небольшое вступление, где уточнить, какой контекст Вы имеете в виду, и кратко изложить то, что Вы написали в комментариях. С этого стоит начать.

Comment: @Lara я не понимаю, почему вы решили, что это off-topic. На мой взгляд, это самый лучший из ответов, которые здесь есть. По крайней мере, он единственный, отметивший, что слово "накликать" никакого отношения к "self-fulfilling prophecy" не имеет, как и "привлекать удачу", и другие предложения, прозвучавшие в ответах.

Comment: @Dima текущий вариант ответа получил свое воплощение благодаря интересу проявленному Lara(с подачи так сказать), оригинальную редакцию вы можете посмотреть [здесь](http://russian.stackexchange.com/revisions/12358/1) успела схлопотать 4 минуса) подозреваю моя английская реплика там была как минимум лишняя.

Comment: @MolbOrg Ну да, I see, that this one is better :). My apologies to Lara :)

Comment: О, теперь совсем другое дело!! Минус убираю, ставлю плюс. Насчет негативной окраски не знаю. Я помню этот термин из курса то ли экономики, то ли социологии, там он нейтрален, как в определении из Википедии: "Самоисполняющееся пророчество — ложное определение ситуации, вызывающее новое поведение, которое превращает первоначальное ложное представление в реальность." А я правильно понимаю, что самоисполняющее пророчество обязательно подразумевает *активные действия*, приводящие его в исполнение? То есть, например, эффект плацебо сюда не относится?

Comment: @Lara бездействие это тоже форма действия. Не очень в курсе относительно плацебо,  в этом случае, как мне кажется основной фокус в этом случае на процессах происходящих в теле, также как аутотренинг, да и просто тренировки к примеру. Определенное сходство есть, но для этих вещей уже есть термины, определяющие эти конкретные ситуации и не требующие привлечения другой терминологии. Возвращаясь к первоисточнику, речь больше о мышлении и ловушках мышления, чем о физических процессах проистекающих в следствии этого, [в эту сторону](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_когнитивных_искажений)

Comment: @JamesNewton And to summarize a bit: considering that the OP asked "is there **a word** in Russian which gives "self-fulfilling prophecy" a positive meaning?" - the answer is probably 'No'. I can not think of such a word and no one in this discussion has come up with any, apparently.